# How to group test suites in jasmine when tests exists in different files?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

As per documentation, we can have groups-sub groups of test suites, but they exists only in one file like below

```
describe('Main Group - Module 1', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

    describe('sub group - 1', function () { // Sub group        
        // specs goes here
    });

     describe('sub group - 2', function () { // Sub group       
        // specs goes here
    });
});
```

If I want to keep **sub group -1** & **sub group -2** in two different files, how can I group these two subgroups in Main Group - Module?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately what you are asking for is currently not possible, although its more of a limitation of javascript rather than jasmine. In that there is no way for a function to be declared across several files.

Comment: What version of Jasmine are you running?

Answer (score 4):

My use case for this is Jasmine-Node, so the `require` statements don't make any difference for me. If you're doing browser-based Jasmine, you'll have to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for this solution. Alternatively, without require statements, you can use [this example from the Jasmine repo issues](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/issues/644).

**file1.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
    describe('sub group - 1', function () { // Sub group        
        // specs goes here
    });
};
```

**file2.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
    describe('sub group - 2', function () { // Sub group        
        // specs goes here
    });
};
```

**file3.js**

```
var subgroup1 = require( './file1.js' );
var subgroup2 = require( './file2.js' );

describe('Main Group - Module 1', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

    subgroup1();
    subgroup2();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

**file1.js**

```
describe('Main Group - Module 1', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

    describe('sub group - 1', function () { // Sub group        
        // specs goes here
    });

});
```

**file2.js**

```
describe('Main Group - Module 1', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('app');
    });

     describe('sub group - 2', function () { // Sub group       
        // specs goes here
    });
});
```

Notice the same parent name.

Comment: I tried this, but when the test case report generates, it will be displayed as two different groups. :(

Comment: This works for me -- @ShivKumar, did you make sure the descriptions are identical?

Comment: Yes Kevin, I actually use karma-html reported to generate it.